# Do regularization models split my data up automatically?

Tags: regression, lasso, regularization

If I simply run a Lasso with y as dependent, x1,x2 as interesting and x3,x4,x5 as "choose from". Does Lasso automatically split my data up into training and validation sets? I've never really understood if that is what it's doing or not because I've seen people manually doing this beforehand in some tutorials.

Comment: What your program does, exactly, depends on your software. You have to look in the manual. I think this is a Stata question.

Comment: Unfortunately can't find any information on this in the manual. Would I ask this question again under "stata" tag?

Comment: No, questions about software are off topic here, sorry

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, I have had similar questions closed under the stata tag before and was confused. I'll find a different platform to ask these types of questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a little confused about what you mean. Lasso is a specific type of regression algorithm that given some input, produces output predictions. It has nothing to do with splitting data — you have to do that manually.

Comment: Then what do cross-validation folds do, if not split the data?

Comment: Cross validation is a specific technique that is distinct from your model. That splits the data. Of course, you can use Lasso regression WITH cross validation. This is good for 1) checking generalization error and 2) comparing performance with similar models.